# question marks php html

Tags: php, html, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a html form, into a php script (in a php file)

the form title, the field title, and so on, are showing well but the content which is introduced by the user into the form, when it has "á, é, í, ó, ú" or "ñ" the output of the script, converts these characters into "??"

I have set

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

and

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

in all the files involving the form (also the character allowed into the form) and the action url also has that config.

but, my special chars still are converted to "??"

any clue? thanks

EDIT: files are encoding in utf8 also tried in utf8-without bom

EDIT 2:

my form is:

```
<form action="file.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">';
                <label>
                    <span>trailer</span>
                    <input  type="text" name="calidad">
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Mediainfo (requerido)</span>
                    <textarea name="mediainfo"></textarea>
                </label>

            <input type="hidden" name="board" id="board" value=' .  $foro . '>

                <label>
                    <span>info</span>
                    <input placeholder="" type="text" name="info" tabindex="3" required>
                </label>

            <input class="botonsubmit" type="submit" value="Postear" name="sub2">
</form>
```

file.php only uses

```
$mediainfo = request_var('mediainfo','');
```

then i echo that variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: try using htmlspecialchars() on your form submission

Comment: is not a duplicate, this problem does not involve mysql, its only php and mysql

Comment: read that link again. Sure it contains stuff about mysql, but also contains information about UTF-8.

Comment: that link gives the lines i have said i added, so the problem is that even with all that stuff the problem is there yet

Comment: there are more things to check, such as the file's encoding. what is it? ansi? utf-8? if utf-8, is it with or without BOM?

Comment: as i said, the files have utf8 encoding, in the edit i put more info

Comment: *"when it has "á, é, í, ó, ú" or "ñ" the output of the script"* - you'll have to show us that script. Your question/code is unclear and doesn't support the question/problem.

Comment: added the form and the data requesting on the action php

Answer (score 0):

While saving the form use:

```
utf8_encode($_POST['fieldname'])
```

While showing the form value:

```
utf8_decode($_POST['fieldname'])
```

Comment: tried, same result, "??" on every word with special characters

Answer (score 0):

You have to change The apache server conf too
In httpd.conf add (or change if it's already there):

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```